# why buffers should be aligned on 64-byte boundary for best performance?

Tags: c++, memory-management, latency

In [this](https://github.com/majek/openonload/blob/master/src/tests/ef_vi/efsink.c) example program I've found this note:

```
/* Hardware delivers at most ef_vi_receive_buffer_len() bytes to each
 * buffer (default 1792), and for best performance buffers should be
 * aligned on a 64-byte boundary.  Also, RX DMA will not cross a 4K
 * boundary.  The I/O address space may be discontiguous at 4K boundaries.
 * So easiest thing to do is to make buffers always be 2K in size.
 */
#define PKT_BUF_SIZE         2048
```

I'm interested why `for best performance buffers should be aligned on a 64-byte boundary`? Why, for example 2000 buffers are slower than 2048 buffers? I guess this is how 64-bit computer works - by some reason it's faster to memcpy 2048 bytes than 2000 bytes?

Why exactly 2048 buffers are faster and may be you can link "minimal example" where "bigger but 64-byte aligned" buffers are faster?

Comment: You think "64 bit" has any relation to "64 bytes"?

Comment: @KerrekSB ok, may be my guess is wrong then

Answer (score 12, accepted):

64 bytes is a popular size of a *cache line* on contemporary architectures. Any fetch from memory fetches entire cache lines. By aligning data to the cache line boundaries, you minimize the number of cache lines that need to be fetched to read your data and that are dirtied when you write your data.

Of course the size of your data is important, too. For example, if the size of the data divides the size of the cache line, it's perfectly fine to align only on the size.

By contrast, suppose your data is 96 bytes large. If you align on 32 bytes, you may use up to three cache lines:

```
|............DDDD|DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD|DDDD............|
```

By contrast, if you align on 64 bytes (necessitating another 32 bytes of padding), you only ever need two cache lines:

```
|................|DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD|DDDDDDDDPPPPPPPP|
```

(`D` = data, `P` = padding, each character represents 4 bytes.)

Cache lines are even more of a concern when you modify memory concurrently. Every time you dirty one cache line, all other CPUs that have fetched the same cache line may potentially have to discard and refetch those. Accidentally placing unrelated, shared data on the same cache line is known as "false sharing", and the insertion of padding is usually used to avoid that.

Comment: Could you please provide a practical example of how this can be implemented in code?

Comment: @Dave: It could be something simple like adding explicit "padding" (e.g. char arrays) into your class definition, or use `alignas`...

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that a data cache line on most contemporary x64 processors is 64 bytes wide, so every fetch that a CPU does from main memory is 64 bytes at a time. If you're loading a 64-byte struct that straddles the 64-byte boundary, then the CPU has to fetch two cache lines to get the whole struct.

The real answer is that this too complex a topic to fit into an answer box, but [Ulrich Drepper's excellent "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory" paper](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) will give you a complete explanation.

Also note that the 64-byte thing isn't a basic law of computing nor is it related to 64-bit processors. It just happens to be the most common cache line size on the x64 processors that are in most workstations today. Other processors have different cache line sizes (for example, the Xenon PowerPC used in the Xbox360 and PS3 has a 128-byte cache line).